# Chinese remaining theorem, help with surjectivity

Tags: ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I_1, \dots, I_n \subset R$ be ideals, which are pairwise coprime. Let furthermore $\pi_j:R \to R/I_j,\; r \mapsto r + I_j$, $j=1, \dots, n$ be the projection to the $jth$ quotient ring.

I know that for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, the ideals $I_j$ and $\cap_{i \neq j}I_i$ are coprime. For all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ we take $d_j \in I_j$ and $e_j \in \cap_{i \neq j}I_i$ s.t. $d_j + e_j=1$.
$$\Rightarrow \pi_i(e_j)=\pi_i(1-d_j)$$
This is now equal to $0$, if $i \neq j$ and equal to $1+I_j$, if $ i=j$. I don't see why we get this.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideals $I_j$ and $\bigcap_{i\ne j} I_i$ are coprime, which means that $I_j + \bigcap_{i\ne j} I_i = R$. Thus for $1\in R$ there are $d_j\in I_j$ and $e_j\in \bigcap_{i\ne j} I_i$ with $d_j+e_j=1.$

Then $\pi_i(e_j) = 0$, since $e_j\in I_i$ for $i\ne j$.

Comment: yes but why i get for i.e. that for $i \neq j$ $\pi_i(e_j)=0$?

Comment: Added comment above

Comment: I go it, ty! :)